# Algoritmo simulação de taxímetro

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Estou  criando um algoritmo em Javascript para fazer o cálculo semelhante ao de um táximetro, onde você tem o horário da **bandeira 1** e da **bandeira 2**.

```
function test(hora,bandeira1, bandeira2) {
  if (hora >= bandeira1 && hora < bandeira2) {
    console.log("calculou como bandeira 1");
  } else {
  console.log("calculou como bandeira 2");
  } 
}

// Retorna: "calculou como bandeira 2"
test(23,1,7);
```

Se eu realizar um teste passando test(23,8,1) o algoritmo não funcionará corretamente, ele deveria apontar como bandeira 1, mas aponta como bandeira 2.

Poderiam me ajudar a fazer um algoritmo onde qualquer combinação que eu passe prevaleça a ordem normal de um taxímetro?

Answer (score 2):

O correto é

```
Hora é maior ou igual que bandeira1 ? && Hora é menor que a bandeira2 ?
   console.log("calculou como bandeira 1");
Não
   console.log("calculou como bandeira 2");
```

Veja

```js
function test(hora,bandeira1, bandeira2) {
  if (hora >= bandeira1 && hora < bandeira2) {
    console.log("calculou como bandeira 1");
  } else {
    console.log("calculou como bandeira 2");
  } 
}

// Retorna: "calculou como bandeira 2"
test(23,1,7);
// Retorna: "calculou como bandeira 1"
test(1,1,7);
// Retorna: "calculou como bandeira 2"
test(7,1,7);
```

Comment: Não funciona para todas as combinações.. se você testar: test(23,8,0) dará como bandeira 2, enquanto deveria ser bandeira 1..

Answer (score 1):

Se o horário nocturno é entre 1am e 7am então tens de isolar esse periodo com  `&&`:

```
hora >= bandeira1 && hora < bandeira2
```

Sugestão:

```js
const taximetro = function( /* N bandeiras */ ) {
  const bandeiras = arguments;
  return function(hora) {
    var match = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < bandeiras.length; i++) {
      var bnd = bandeiras[i];
      if (bnd.inicio <= hora) match = i;
    }
    var res = match !== -1 ? bandeiras[match] : bandeiras[bandeiras.length - 1];
    return "calculou como bandeira " + res.tipo;
  }
};

const taximetroA = taximetro({
  inicio: 2,
  tipo: 'Bandeira Madrugada'
}, {
  inicio: 7,
  tipo: 'Bandeira Dia'
}, {
  inicio: 22,
  tipo: 'Bandeira Noite'
});

for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
  console.log(i, taximetroA(i));
}
```

Comment: Não funciona para todos os testes... Se você passar 8am como bandeira 1 e 1pm como bandeira 2 e for 23hrs calculará errado. @sergio

Comment: @MateusCarvalho nesse caso a resposta não seria `bandeira 2`?

Comment: desculpe falei 1pm como bandeira 2, mas seria 1am, nesse caso ainda deveria dar bandeira 1, mas acaba dando bandeira 2, entendeu?

Comment: @MateusCarvalho estou no trabalho mas posso melhorar a resposta depois com possibilidade para N bandeiras, sem estar tão específico para o exemplo da pergunta.

Comment: agradeço sua ajuda, assim que você puder, obrigado!

Comment: @MateusCarvalho dá uma olhada.